IntelliJ IDEA: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module html2pdf not found
I am using Intellij 2024.1 to build a JavaFX application. And I need external libraries dependency html2pdf. I add it to file build.gradle.
dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.6.0.jre11'
    implementaion 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.31'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:5.7.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-imaging:1.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.0.1'


    implementation 'com.itextpdf:html2pdf:5.0.4'


    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'

}

And add to module-info.java
module org.main.culturesolutioncalculation {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires com.opencsv;

    requires com.zaxxer.hikari;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires html2pdf;


    opens org.main.culturesolutioncalculation to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.main.culturesolutioncalculation;
}

In my code, I import:
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.resolver.font.DefaultFontProvider;

But when I run the project, it shows the error:
> Task :Main.main() FAILED
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module html2pdf not found, required by org.main.culturesolutioncalculation

What should I do to fix this problem? I am a newbie in Java. Thank you!
What should I do to fix this problem? I am a newbie in Java. Thank you!

Are you sure that the html2pdf package is distributed in a Java module? See also [tag:java-module] to Learn more…

The htmlpdf project doesn't seem to have a module-info.java, so it will be treated as an automatic module.  By default, I don't think gradle will place automatic modules on the module path, therefore if you try to required that code as a module, it won't be found.  I don't use gradle so have no fix suggestion for you with a modular project with gradle.

If you convert to a non-modular project (i.e. remove your module-info) following non-modular instructions in the linked document, it will probably work.  Your module-info seems wrong for your dependency set for other dependencies in your project in any case.

To add to jewelsea's first comment, I believe Gradle will put non-modular dependencies on the module path, but only if their manifest contains an Automatic-Module-Name entry. If a dependency doesn't even have that, then its developers haven't begun the process of modularization. And in that case, Gradle will not automatically place it on the module-path. You can add it to the module yourself, but you would probably be better off making your project non-modular; requiring automatic modules, even just one, negates many benefits of modules.

Thank you, all. I converted my project to non-modular and now it's working.

Just wanted to add that Java has many very good features, but its module system is none of them. Personally I have never worked on a project where the Java module system has done anything good, meaningless if it was a private or a commercial one. IMO it's the best practice to just get rid of the module system and simply work with non-modular projects.

The author solved the problem by himself/herself:

Thank you, all. I converted my project to non-modular and now it's
working. –  Anh Tuan  Commented Jun 9 at 6:22

